In Python unittest, how can I access the instance on which a mock method was called?
I have a Python class structure similar to the following example:

class Foo:
   def start(self):
     # do something

class FooBar(Foo):
   def __init__(self, param):
     self.param = param

   def run(self):
     # do something else

class ProductionClass:
   def use_foobar(self):
     foo = FooBar("string")
     foo.start()

Now I want to write a test in which the start method on FooBar (inherited from Foo) is mocked so that the run method defined directly in FooBar is called instead.
I tried it this way:

def test_something(self):
    self.foobar_patcher = patch.object(FooBar, 'start', side_effect=self.mock_start)
    self.foobar_patcher.start()

    ProductionClass().use_foobar()

def mock_start(self):
    the_production_class_instance.run()

In this example, the_production_class_instance is meant to be the instance of FooBar where the start() method was called on, but I can't seem to find a way where to get this instance. The instance is created inside ProductionClass().use_foobar() and discarded after use, so there is no real way to access it from the outside.
Is there a way to achieve this with unittest?

It's not clear from your test case which method are you writing a test case for. You are patching FooBar.start but you want to run FooBar.run. Your test case test_something is calling ProductionClass.use_foobar which is calling FooBar.start but your helper method mock_start is calling FooBar.run. Not only your test cases are deviating from what your your source code is doing, but also they are mixing 2 different methods of FooBar as if they are the same.

Necessary changes to your Production code
To solve your problem I have modified your ProductionClass as following:
class ProductionClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = FooBar("string")
        
    def use_foobar(self):
        self.foo.start()

The differences are:

I have created the method __init__() where is created the attribute foo as an instance of FooBar
In the method use_foobar() is only called the method start() of FooBar inherited from Foo.

So I have saved your production code in the file prod.py that is the following (classes Foo and FooBar are unchanged except for the introduction of the print() instruction in the methods start() and run()):
class Foo:
   def start(self):
     # for execute the code I have substituted 'do_something' with a print()
     print("Foo.start() exec")

class FooBar(Foo):
   def __init__(self, param):
     self.param = param

   def run(self):
     # for execute the code I have substituted 'do_something' with a print()
     print("FooBar.run() exec")
     
class ProductionClass:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = FooBar("string")
        
    def use_foobar(self):
        self.foo.start()

The test code
With the previous changes I think that the following test code could satisfy your requests (the code is saved in the file test_code.py):
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from prod import ProductionClass

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_something(self):
        prod_class = ProductionClass()
        foo_instance = prod_class.foo
        with patch.object(foo_instance, 'start') as mock_start:
            mock_start.start = foo_instance.run()
            prod_class.use_foobar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Output of test execution
If I execute the test code in a terminal with the following command:
/path/to/python/interpreter/python /path/to/test/file/test_prod.py

I get the following output:
FooBar.run() exec
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

and this proof that it is execute the method run() of FooBar instead the method start() of Foo.

@ronin667 Is it useful this answer for you?

the project got abandoned so I didn't implement any solution.
